# Its give error while connecting to 000webhost database

Tags: java, php, android, mysqli

I am new to android and online sql database.Basically i am trying to use 000webhost to use database. I am doing this for the first time. However i am getting error.

```
failureProxySQL Error: Access denied for user 'id234191_faisalahmedansari20'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::3' (using password: YES)
```

my php file is

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="-----";
$password="-----";
$dbName="------";

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbName);

if($con)
{
echo "SUccess";
}
else
{
echo "failure".mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

I think some thing is wrong in php file please help me where i am wrong. Please help me out

Comment: Is your PHP running on a machine provided by the same web host, or somewhere else?

Comment: yes it is on the same webhost